# Using Tabs on AMP Page, how to make fields required on active tab?

Tags: amp-html

I'm using AMP selector with tabs on my AMP page.

Here is HTML sample;

```
<form action="{{$ampxhr}}/cart/confirm.do" method="GET" target="_top">
  <h1 class="text-align-center display-block font-lg">{{__('lang-item.shipping_info')}}</h1>
  <amp-selector class="tabs-with-flex" role="tablist">
    <div id="phonetab" role="tab" aria-controls="tabphone" option selected>
      {{__('lang-cart.contact.phone_tab')}}
    </div>
    <div id="tabphone" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="phonetab" class="content-tab">
      <div class="country-code">
        <select name="country">
          <option value="1">flag 1</option>
          <option value="2">flag 2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <input type="tel" name="phone" value="" autocomplete="" class="phone-input"/>
    </div>
    <div id="mailtab" role="tab" aria-controls="tabmail" option>
      {{__('lang-cart.contact.email_tab')}}
    </div>
    <div id="tabmail" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mailtab" class="content-tab">
      <input type="text" name="email" value="" autocomplete="" class="mail-input continue-input"/>
    </div>
  </amp-selector>

  <button type="submit" class="button-primary font-m display-block">{{__('lang-item.continue_btn')}}</button>
</form>
```

I want to add, `required` attribute., to input on active tab.

You know, we can not use, custom javascript / jQuery on AMP pages, is there any way for make fields required on active tab ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure I understand, why not just add the `required` attribute?

Comment: true one. i need to set required attribute